# Funscript examples - can't connect to server

Tags: f#, funscript

I finally can run the funscript examples. But they do not work as expected.

The last output I get is:

```
Searching for main function...
Found entry point...
Loaded assembly: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
Generated JavaScript in 0.535000 sec...
Thread started: 
Thread started: 
Starting web server at http://localhost:8080/
```

The browser starts but no server is running ?

BTW: I"m using mono and I try to start the Tutorial project from within Xamarin Studio.

Regards
  Roger

Comment: Does the console window stay open? You can also try specifying alternative port by using `Runtime.Run(components=Interop.Components.all, port=99999)`...

Comment: It seems as if this is a Xamarin setup problem. I just discovered that I can run the examples from the command line.

Comment: You might as well just ignore the fact that the server does not start and open the generated `html` file in `bin` in web browser directly. The server is only needed if you're making some cross-domain calls and the browser blocks this if the FunScript web page is opened locally (needs to come from `http`).